# Xamarin Forms android acr.userdialogs lagging during navigation

Tags: c#, android, performance, xamarin.forms, navigation

I am new to xamarin forms, I want to display an activity spinner while it loads the next form and it seems to lag while the form is changing. This is the code I am using to change forms.

```
UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Loading...");
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new Inventory());
                    UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
```

I have added an async method to the next form to load the data from a view model. is there something I am missing or is it normal for the spinner to lag when changing to another form?

Many thanks,

Comment: Hello Martin, Did you found a solution to this issue?

Comment: The answer below worked. i now usually put the showloading before the navigation and the hide loading on the new form after loaded.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could put the `ShowLoading()` method into the `OnAppearing()` method of `Inventory` page.
And call the `HideLoading()` method after you finish loading data.

For example:

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Loading...");
    }
    public Inventory()
    {           
        TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);
        Device.StartTimer(interval,()=> {
            InitializeComponent();
            UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
            return true;
        });          
    }
```

Comment: This did not work as expected. This message is not being displayed at all.